# Novels about a time traveller who fixes a major problem, then investigates the Kennedy assassination

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

A long time ago (late 70s/ early 80s), I had a 2 book series about a man who came from the distant future to a pivotal point in the past (around the 70s) to 'fix' something that went wrong. He ended up working with a Rand consultant to fix the problem.  At the end of the first book he announced that his time travel was a one way trip, and that he was now stuck in the past, and they set up some kind of new investigative firm.

In the second book they were investigating the Kennedy assassination, and the book ended with the man from the future being captured and dropped into some kind of time-bubble black hole...

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but this has been bugging me for years that I cant remember anything else about them... and haven't been able to track anything down...

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the *[Mind Brothers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/105054-mind-brothers)* series by Peter Heath (pseudonym for Robert Irvine). There were actually three books: *The Mind Brothers*, *Assassins from Tomorrow*, and *Men Who Die Twice*.

The first book has a man, Adam Cyber, make a one-way trip from the future to fix the past. And the second book, *[Assassins from Tomorrow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6339783-assassins-from-tomorrow)*, was indeed about the Kennedy assassination.

> The mystery of the Kennedy assassination has attracted many amateur investigators—but none quite like young Mark Brown, the brilliant but footloose young son of America’s leading theoretical physicist. Like others, Mark Brown had only a theory to work on. Unlike others, his theory led him straight into trouble—and into even deeper mystery…
>
> Mark Brown needed help—and that help could only come from Jason Starr and Adam Cyber, the Mind Brothers. The three made up a team of scientific brains unmatched in human history—but the problem they faced was enormous. The complexities included a mysterious artificial satellite and a weird organization called “Sutra”…and the only thing certain was that at least one of the three would die. The biggest question was whether the Earth would die, too….